# default docker-machine ip

Tags: macos, docker

normally, the default docker-machine ip is 192.168. 99.100. I work on MAC and want to check it , but when I type

```
$docker-machine ip
```

I have the following error message :

```
Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists.
```

What can I do ?

Comment: docker-machine ip is when there is no support for docker on the OS. For e.g docker desktop with windows 7(this is where we use docker toolbox). why do you need docker-machine ip with mac?

Comment: Hello error404, I want to request an API from angular to the application which is hosted on docker

Comment: So, I use the url http://192.168.99.100:5555/api/produit/produits

Comment: You don't need machine-ip..just expose the port using `-p 5555:5555` when your container starts and then hit the `localhost:5555/api/produit/produits`